# All cross sections of a volume

Tags: geometry, cross-sections

Is there a elegant or analytical way to determine all the possible shape cross section shapes of a volume given the particular volume?

Example (by brute force slicing a plane through said volume in 3ds max...):

- Cube - rectangle/square, triangle, trapezoid, pentagon, hexagon
- Cylinder - Circle, ellipse, rectangle/square, octagon (?)

Comment: Every shape is possible, because affine planes have volume (Lebesgue measure) 0 in 3 dimension. We may thus take a cube of your desired volume and add any 2d shape in an affine plane to this structure without increasing the total volume.

Comment: By "volume", do you mean a three-dimensional figure, a set of points in three-dimensional space? That word commonly denotes the measure of such a set of points.That is, a cube _has_ volume; I think it is relatively rare to say that a cube _is_ a volume. As such, the "volume" tag seems inappropriate. (I don't see the applicability of the number theory or general topology tags, either.)

Comment: I just mean the common volumes found in Common Core mathematics... Cube, Cylinder, Cone, Pyramid, Sphere

Comment: Basically: I'm asking about whether you can slice a plane into {cube, cylinder, cone, pyramid, sphere} to get other 2D "shapes"

Comment: @StefanMesken : From one point of view your comment answers the question, but from the point of view of the kind of geometry that this is about, it doesn't seem to shed light. Probably there should be a hypothesis that these shapes are well behaved in some reasonable sense, and then your comment would no longer be true.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sure. My comment was intended to point out that, as written, OP's answer is meaningless -- hence should be stated more carefully.

Comment: @StefanMesken : It is not _meaningless_; rather it is, from a certain point of view, imperfectly stated. And in this case I'm inclined to suspect that the appearance of imperfection is an illusion resulting from flaws in our standard ways of thinking about mathematics.